# COUNT(*) on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need to count how many users online. I have it in two tables, here's the first table:

```
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
 |      id     |     name    |    status   |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
 |      1      |     name    |    1        |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
 |      2      |     name    |    1        |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
 |      3      |     name    |    0        |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Second table:

```
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
 |      id     |    userid   |  friend_id  |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
 |      1      |      1      |    2        |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
 |      2      |      1      |    2        |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
 |      3      |      2      |    3        |
 +-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Ie how many users at the other table where `user_id = 1` and how many are online.

Comment: I suppose the status field indicates wether a user is online or not? Then why do you need the second table?

Comment: The second table are now friends say the user with id 1 has a friend with id 2 
and I need to find out how many friends id 1 is online

Comment: You should at least include a try you've made to achieve it - then users will easier help you instead of doing some work you should have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables together and then do the counting.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1 AS t1 
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.friendID)
WHERE t2.userID = 1
```